# Command fails when running in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting, registry

I can run this command via command line:

```
      REG QUERY "HKLM\someregkey" > c:\filename.text
```

then I can run a loop to read line by line and export each subkey

```
      FOR /F "usebackq tokens=6 delims=\" %G IN       ("c:\filename.txt") DO (REG EXPORT "HKLM\someregkey\%G" "E:\directory\%G.reg" /y)
```

But when I run it in batch, I get a 1> and it won't execute. I had this issue a long time ago but forgot how I passed it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`1>` is the correct command for redirection. For MSDos compatibility reasons CMD automatically fixes `>` to `1>`. You only get to see it happening in batch files. The `1` is filehandle **1**, the console screen (stdout), **0** is the keyboard (stdin), **2** is error sent to screen (stderr).

Your code doesn't work in a batch file because you need to use `For` variables `%%G`. `%G` when typed, `%%G` in a batch. See `for /?`.